# Synchronize jquery animations in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization

I have a `runner` function that should only return when all stuff (also animations) in the called callback are finished.

```
function runner(callback) {
  callback.call();
  return; // only return when callback is finished with everything.
}
```

I thought about using the jQuery `queue` function, but I could not get it working. Is it even possible to archive that. `callback` is a blackbox. `runner` is not able to know whats going up in there.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is for `callback` to take a callback of its own. (I know you said it's a black box, but it needs to be, well, a different black box.) Then instead of waiting for the callback to return, you just pass the continuation to it and `callback` is responsible for assigning that continuation to the completion handler on the animation (or whatever it does). So instead of:

```
doSomeStuff();
runner(callback);
doMoreStuff();
```

you want

```
doSomeStuff();
callback.call(doMoreStuff);
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578137/wait-for-animation-to-finish-then-return) an answer to a related question. More generally, this pattern is [continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) and is central to how jQuery handles things.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the jQuery callbacks. Unfortunately there is really no way to manipulate the blackbox. So if you are right then it seems that there isn't really a solution without touching the blackbox.

Comment: I see. Hmm, you should be able to do it with $.queue(). Can you update the question with what you tried?

Comment: Actually, I take that back. I don't think `queue()` can work because you don't know what elements to attach it to, because you don't know anything about what the callback is animating. So I think you'll have to crack open `callback`.